# How can I edit Prestashop's code in VSC, from Docker container?

Tags: php, docker, prestashop

How can I display Prestashop code in VSC?
I run Prestashop like in docs

```
# create a network for containers to communicate
$ docker network create prestashop-net
# launch mysql 5.7 container
$ docker run -ti --name some-mysql --network prestashop-net -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -p 3307:3306 -d mysql:5.7
# launch prestashop container
$ docker run -ti --name some-prestashop --network prestashop-net -e DB_SERVER=some-mysql -p 8080:80 -d prestashop/prestashop
```

And it works but I don't know how can I display my code in VSC. I tryed use *Remote Containers* but I can't find my container (i tryed found by code and name).

I tryed run Prestashop via docker-compose up (project from github). My terminal show that my project run but website doesn't work at 8001 port.

For me is no matter how I run Prestashop but I need to run Prestashop in Docker and I need to edit the code.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation you see there's a

`PS_DEV_MODE: The constant _PS_MODE_DEV_ will be set at true (default value: 0)`

but you can run an interactive terminal into the running container.

```
docker exec -it some-prestashop bash
```

You can then do an ls, cd etc to navigate around in the container.  You type exit to get out of it.  There are ways to copy stuff back and forth from the container host to/from the container.

Comment: Will I open that folder into VSC by core ., won't you? Or by Remote Container?